# SQL join two tables and the elements that satisfies one condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Good afternoon,

I'm having an issue with two tables that I'm trying to join.

What I am trying to do is, I have to print a table with all products that is registered in some agenda (codControl), so the person can put his price.

But first I have to look into **lctocotacao** to see if he had already given a price to some product. But when I do this, I just get the products that has some price, and the other ones I dont see.

Here is an example of my table **cadprodutoscotacao**

```
codProduct      desc      codControl
1               abc       197
2               cde       197
3               fgh       197
1               abc       198
```

And my table **lctocotacao**

```
codProduct     price     codControl    codPerson
1              2.5000    197           19
2              3.0000    197           37
3              4.5000    198           37
```

I have this SQL statement at the moment:

```
SELECT cadc.cod, cadc.desc, lcto.codEnt, lcto.price
FROM cadprodutoscotacao cadc JOIN lctocotacao lcto
ON cadc.codControl = lcto.codControl
AND cadc.codProduct = lcto.codProduct
AND cadc.codControl = '197'
AND lcto.codPerson = '19'
ORDER BY cadc.codControl;
```

What I'm getting:

```
cod     desc     price     codPerson     codControl
1       abc      2.5000    19            197
```

And the table I expect

```
cod     desc     price     codPerson     codControl
1       abc      2.5000    19            197
2       cde                              197
3       fgh                              197
```

197 and 19 will be parameters to my query.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

**E D I T**

Basically, I have two queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM cadprodutoscotacao
WHERE cadc_codControl = '197'
```

This first, to return all products registered in the agenda '197'.

And the second one:

```
SELECT *
FROM lctocotacao
WHERE codPerson = 19
AND codControl = '197'
```

This second one to return products that already has some price added by the Person 19 in the agenda 197.

I have to return one table, including all records from the first query, and, if there is some price in the second one, I have to "concatenate" them.

[image: Example]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for a `left join`:

Comment: I'm not sure. I just added an image, I think you can see what I'm expecting now.

Comment: not sure if it helps... There's something highly unclear: you search specifically for person 19, but you want the results of person 37.... You say that you want to **concatenate** the prices, but the one that show up in your results is 2,50 which correspond to the price of person 37 and in the column beside it shows person 19... I just don't know.

Comment: I fixed it. And the image is another example.
But Gordon Linoff just got me an excellent answer! Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`, but you also need to be careful about the filtering conditions:

```
SELECT cadc.cod, cadc.desc, lcto.codEnt, lcto.price
FROM cadprodutoscotacao cadc LEFT JOIN
     lctocotacao lcto
     ON cadc.codControl = lcto.codControl AND
        cadc.cod = lcto.cod AND
        lcto.codEnt = '19'
WHERE cadc.codControl = '197'
ORDER BY cadc_codigo;
```

A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table, regardless of whether a match is found in the `ON` conditions.  This applies to conditions on the first table as well as the second.  Hence, you don't want to put filters on the first table in the `ON` clause.

The rule is:  When using `LEFT JOIN` put filters on the first table in the `WHERE` clause.  Filters on the second table go in the `ON` clause (otherwise the outer join is generally turned into an inner join).

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! It is an intereting approach.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your rows are filtered because you specified `JOIN`, which is a shortcut for  `INNER JOIN`

If you want all the records from the left table, even if they don't have correlated records in the right table, you should do a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT cadc.cod, cadc.desc, lcto.codEnt, lcto.price
FROM cadprodutoscotacao cadc 
LEFT JOIN lctocotacao lcto
ON cadc.codControl = lcto.codControl
AND cadc.cod = lcto.cod
AND cadc.codControl = '197'
AND lcto.codEnt = '19'
ORDER BY cadc_codigo;
```

Comment: The problem with LEFT JOIN is that it will return to me all records inside **cadprodutoscotacao**, and I need only the ones that are in this query:

`SELECT *
FROM cadprodutoscotacao
WHERE cadc_codcotacao = '197'`

Comment: you changed the data in your original question, right ? It had a record  `4 ,'ijk', 198` in `cadprodutoscotacao` and I don't see it anymore. I've got a serious issue with your table structure because the table/column names arent meaningful at all and this confuse me a lot. I have put all this in SQLfiddle and I'll come with another query

Comment: Yeah! This `cadprodutoscotacao` is the table that contains all products registered in all agendas.
So the codProduct can be repeated, because the same product can be in more than one agenda.

Comment: I just added an image, I think you can see what I'm expecting now.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your example. What are the primary keys? "cod" and "codentry" appear in both tables. Your schema seems to be very redundant.

But whenever someone JOINs and is missing some entries, it might be solved by using a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: The `cod` is the auto-increment key from each table.
I have to filter them using the codEnt, that comes from a third table, and I get this codEnt in the session from my web-app

Comment: so why do you compare auto-increment values with each other?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. they are not auto-increment. they are the Product cod.

I made an update in the end, I think it is easier to understand now.

Comment: I just added an image, I think you can see what I'm expecting now.